# Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Timeout was reached: Send failure: Connection was reset

Tags: r, api, youtube, timeout

I am trying to extract comments from 5000 videos from Youtube's API. 
My code works perfectly when I download 5 videos or more but when I plug the entire list of videos that I want, it throws the below error after running for hours. I am not sure what it means or if it is a memory problem. Thank you!

**Line of code in R:**

```
 comments_1 <- CollectDataYoutube(video1,key,writeToFile = FALSE)
```

video1: is a list of 5 thousand videos codes that I have so that the API extracts comments from it directly.

key: is my API key stored in an object

**Error message:**

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>     Timeout was reached: Send failure: Connection was reset

Answer (score 5):

RCurl can only keep open an internet connection for so long to stream data in. It's an internet latency problem, not a memory problem. You'd be better off batching your requests in smaller batches and then combining them.